# Як перекласти вислів "Валять дурака" на українську?

Tags: переклад, from-russian, фразеологізми, розмовна-українська

В російській мові є вираз "Валять дурака", а на сайті [Мислово](http://myslovo.com/?dictionary=%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%97%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F) я знайшов варіант "клеїти дурня", який, як мені здається, підійде для перекладу. Однак, чи існують в українській мові ще якісь варіанти перекладу? Адже якось мені доводилося чути від викладачів мого університету таку фразу як "запускати сміховинки", яка також, на мою думку, може бути перекладом данного виразу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Згідно із **[Фразеологічним словником української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53396/357398.html)** маємо таке визначення

> **валя́ти (кле́їти) ду́рня**. **1.** *Робити дурниці, безглузді вчинки; поводитися не так, як слід.* Петрусь сів. Просто на вогкий, холодний
>   гравій.— Хлопчики, викидайте мене разом з добром, більше я ні на що не
>   здатен.— Кинь дурня клеїти! — розсердився, аж викрикнув Валет (П.
>   Дорошко). **валя́ти дурака́.** (Вареник:) Демку, побратиме, перестань
>   смішить людей, не соромся. Ну що ти дурака валяєш? (М. Кропивницький).
>   **стро́їти ду́рня.** — Тільки от що, Маріє,— затримав її Давид,— Хай Тихін дурня не строїть, нехай лікується (А. Головко). **2.** *Прикидатися
>   таким, що нічого не розуміє, не знає.* — Скажи мені, Давид, от у вас, у
>   Грузії, що роблять такій людині, яка в бою дурня клеїть. Га? (Ю.
>   Яновський). **3.** *Нічого
>   не робити, байдикувати.* — В Голодний Степ везе, каже, працювати будеш,
>   нема чого дурня валяти (Іван Ле).

Відповідно лише до 3 значення можемо додати такі **[синоніми](http://dovidka.biz.ua/biti-baydiki-znachennya-frazeologizmu/)**

> - посиденьки справляти, байдикувати;
> - гав (ґави) ловити;
> - горобцям дулі давати;
> - лежати лежнем;
> - і за холодну воду не браться;
> - горобців лічити;
> - у стелю плювати;
> - лежні справляти.